# how to get a handle on an attribute directive for unit testing? final release

Tags: unit-testing, angular

When we want to get a handle on a service in Angular2 we do ...

```
let fix = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
let injector = fix.debugElement.injector;
let service = injector.get(MyService);
```

and now we can spy on the injected service, etc.

How can I get a handle on an attribute directive that is used by a test component so that I can spy on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get it from the child injector

```
let directive = fixture.debugElement.children[0].injector.get(MyDirective);
```

Comment: thanks very much. gonna accept this answer although it assumes that children[0] is a directive element. Have provided my own answer which does not make this assumption. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Slight tweak on @peeskillet answer which only targets elements tied to the directive in question.

```
    let fix = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    // this will return multiple elements if the test component uses the directive multiple times
    let directiveEls = fix.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(MyDirective));
    let directive = directiveEls[0].injector.get(MyDirective) as MyDirective;
```

Comment: Much better answer.